# Validating String Using SQL Regex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a SQL Regex that validates the following criteria:

- The string must have at least one Capital character anywhere in the string
- The string must have at least one number anywhere in the string
- The string can contain special characters
- The string must be of length greater than 6 and less than 16

With SQL so far I have got this

```
declare @password varchar(1000) = '1hEl@'
select (case when len(@password) between 4 and 16 AND
        @password COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN like '%[A-Z]%[A-Z0-9]%[A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()]%' 
        THEN 'Match' 
    ELSE 'Not Match' 
end)

output
1hEl@ ==  'Not Match'
1hE1l@ == 'Match'

expected output
1hEl@ ==  'Match'
1hE1l@ == 'Match'
```

I understand that this should be done at the application level but I got to write a stored procedure to validate password complexity for an application using my database.

I have been following the below link:

[Regular Expressions in SQL Server Databases](https://study.com/academy/lesson/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-databases-implementation-use.html)

Comment: Passwords should never be getting to the database in plain text. The application should be validating the password and passing salt and hash values to the database. Never store (or pass) plain text passwords to a data engine; it's a huge security risk.

Comment: Considering that SQL Server doesn't (natively) support REGEX as well, this'll be much easier in your application.

Comment: You should be doing this within your application as a field validation even before its submitted anywhere near a database engine. Even then it should be encrypted by some means and no other manipulations conducted. When validated against the stored password that should then have the salt and hash applied then compared to what the SQL Server holds

Comment: Why have you "got to" to it in an SP? If this were me, and the business was driving it this would be something I would adamantly refuse to do because of said security issues. This is something that **must** be pushed back on and send back up stream to the application developers to handle *properly*.

Comment: Why should `1hEl@` produce `Match`? Its length is only **5**...

Comment: **length** of `1hEl@` is **5** so it `Not Match`

Comment: Aside from this being just a horrific way of handling passwords you can't do this in t-sql. The complexity of string validation here requires a regex. If business simply won't listen to rational discussion about properly handling passwords you are going to need to use CLR for this.

Comment: You will never take security and best practices seriously when you wave your hands and claim "i must do it this way because of my application".

Comment: if you change the query to 'between 4 and 16 AND ' it stills gives Not Match, as the question updated. Moreover, I completely understand the security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do multiple `like`

```
    declare @password varchar(100) = 'eeee@9A';

    select case when len(@password) between 4 and 16
                and
                @password COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN like '%[a-z]%'
                and
                @password COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN like '%[A-Z]%'
                and
                @password like '%[0-9]%'
                and
                @password like '%[!@#$%^&*()]%'
            then
                'Match'
            else
                'Not Match' 
            end
```

P.S. it's better not to send the sensitive information in plain text to database.